# Fetching contacts by alphabetical groups

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I've got my table view all set up to fetch contacts using the contacts framework. Currently, I have the following table view:

[image]

I am fetching my contacts with the CNContactStore.I am able to retrieve all the data I want out of my contacts.

I created the following struct that contains an array of **ExpandableNames** where each **ExpandableNames** contains an isExpanded boolean and an array of **FavoritableContact**.

```
struct ExpandableNames{
    var isExpanded: Bool
    var contacts: [FavoritableContact]
}

struct FavoritableContact {
    let contact: CNContact
    var hasFavorited: Bool
}
```

With this, I declared and initialized the following array:

```
var favoritableContacts = [FavoritableContact]()
```

As well as:

```
var twoDimensionalArray = [ExpandableNames]()
```

Once I initialized my arrays, I created a function that would fetch my contacts.

```
    private func fetchContacts(){

            let store = CNContactStore()

            store.requestAccess(for: (.contacts)) { (granted, err) in
                if let err = err{
                    print("Failed to request access",err)
                    return
                }

                if granted {
                    print("Access granted")
                     let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
                    let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])
                    var favoritableContacts = [FavoritableContact]()

                    fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault

                    do {
                        try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { ( contact, error) -> Void in
                            favoritableContacts.append(FavoritableContact(contact: contact, hasFavorited: false))
                        })

                        let names = ExpandableNames(isExpanded: true, contacts: favoritableContacts)
                        self.twoDimensionalArray = [names]



                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    }
                    catch let error as NSError {
                        print(error.localizedDescription)
                    }


                }else{
                    print("Access denied")
                }
            }       

}
```

With this in mind, Is there a way for me to fetch these contacts in groups. When I say groups, I mean fetching contacts in alphabetical order from the ContactsUI like this:

[image]

I've tried other ways but I keep hitting the same wall where I need to take into account the fact that the standard English language alphabet might not be the user's preferred device language, diacritics, symbols, numbers and more. Therefore, If I could just retrieve it the way it is from the contactsUI, it would be great.

Thank you guys!

**NOTE**: if you want more details let me know!

Comment: Research the `UILocalizedIndexedCollation` class.

Answer (score 8):

**SOLUTION SWIFT 4**

I was able to find the solution with the help of rmaddy using the UILocalizedIndexedCollation class.

The following code represents my ConctactsVC:

```
import UIKit
import Contacts

class ContactsVC: UITableViewController {

    let cellID = "cellID"

    var contacts = [Contact]()
    var contactsWithSections = [[Contact]]()
    let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.current() // create a locale collation object, by which we can get section index titles of current locale. (locale = local contry/language)
    var sectionTitles = [String]()

    private func fetchContacts(){

        let store = CNContactStore()

        store.requestAccess(for: (.contacts)) { (granted, err) in
            if let err = err{
                print("Failed to request access",err)
                return
            }

            if granted {
                print("Access granted")
                let keys = [CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactPhoneNumbersKey]
                let fetchRequest = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: keys as [CNKeyDescriptor])

                fetchRequest.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrder.userDefault

                do {
                    try store.enumerateContacts(with: fetchRequest, usingBlock: { ( contact, error) -> Void in

                        guard let phoneNumber = contact.phoneNumbers.first?.value.stringValue else {return}
                        self.contacts.append(Contact(givenName: contact.givenName, familyName: contact.familyName, mobile: phoneNumber))

                    })

                    for index in self.contacts.indices{

                        print(self.contacts[index].givenName)
                        print(self.contacts[index].familyName)
                        print(self.contacts[index].mobile)
                    }

                    self.setUpCollation()

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
                catch let error as NSError {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }


            }else{
                print("Access denied")
            }
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()



        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(dimissContactsVC))
        navigationItem.title = "Contacts"
        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true

        //Changing section index color
        self.tableView.sectionIndexColor = UIColor.red


        // need to register a custom cell
        tableView.register(ContactsCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: cellID)


         fetchContacts()

        //Test

//        let contact1 = Contact(name: "Anuska", mobile: "123434")
//
//        let contact2 = Contact(name: "Anuj Sinha", mobile: "2321234")
//
//        let contact3 = Contact(name: "Maria", mobile: "343434")
//
//        let contact4 = Contact(name: "Jacob", mobile: "34454545")
//
//        let contact5 = Contact(name: "Macculam", mobile: "455656")
//
//        let contact6 = Contact(name: "Sophia", mobile: "4567890")
//
//        self.contacts = [contact1, contact2, contact3, contact4, contact5, contact6]


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    @objc func setUpCollation(){
        let (arrayContacts, arrayTitles) = collation.partitionObjects(array: self.contacts, collationStringSelector: #selector(getter: Contact.givenName))
        self.contactsWithSections = arrayContacts as! [[Contact]]
        self.sectionTitles = arrayTitles

        print(contactsWithSections.count)
        print(sectionTitles.count)
    }

    @objc func dimissContactsVC(){
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sectionTitles.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return contactsWithSections[section].count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID, for: indexPath) as! ContactsCell
        let cell = ContactsCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellID)

        cell.link = self // custom delegation

        let contact = contactsWithSections[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        cell.selectionStyle = .default
        cell.textLabel?.text = contact.givenName + " " + contact.familyName
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = contact.mobile

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return sectionTitles[section]
    }

    //Changing color for the Letters in the section titles
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view:UIView, forSection: Int) {
        if let headerTitle = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView {
            headerTitle.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.red
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {
        return sectionTitles
    }

}

extension UILocalizedIndexedCollation {
    //func for partition array in sections
    func partitionObjects(array:[AnyObject], collationStringSelector:Selector) -> ([AnyObject], [String]) {
        var unsortedSections = [[AnyObject]]()

        //1. Create a array to hold the data for each section
        for _ in self.sectionTitles {
            unsortedSections.append([]) //appending an empty array
        }
        //2. Put each objects into a section
        for item in array {
            let index:Int = self.section(for: item, collationStringSelector:collationStringSelector)
            unsortedSections[index].append(item)
        }
        //3. sorting the array of each sections
        var sectionTitles = [String]()
        var sections = [AnyObject]()
        for index in 0 ..< unsortedSections.count { if unsortedSections[index].count > 0 {
            sectionTitles.append(self.sectionTitles[index])
            sections.append(self.sortedArray(from: unsortedSections[index], collationStringSelector: collationStringSelector) as AnyObject)
            }
        }
        return (sections, sectionTitles)
    }
}
```

I also have a model file called Contact:

```
@objc class Contact : NSObject {
    @objc var givenName: String!
    @objc var familyName: String!
    @objc var mobile: String!

    init(givenName: String, familyName: String, mobile: String) {
        self.givenName = givenName
        self.familyName = familyName
        self.mobile = mobile
    }
}
```

**PICTURE:**

[image]

Comment: what if we only want to show only Alphabets at right side for tapping and moving through contacts and disable or hide the header alphabets?? Is there any way?

Answer (score -1):

I managed to solve it like this.

```
//keys with fetching properties
NSArray *keys = @[CNContactFamilyNameKey, CNContactGivenNameKey, CNContactEmailAddressesKey];
CNContactFetchRequest *request = [[CNContactFetchRequest alloc] initWithKeysToFetch:keys];

//Order contacts by Surname.
request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrderFamilyName;

--OR YOU CAN--

//Order contacts by Name.
request.sortOrder = CNContactSortOrderGivenName;
```

Comment: The question explicitly states that contacts need to be grouped alphabetically. Notice the pictures they included. All this does is sort it by surname. They want it sorted into groups ordered by surname

Comment: @DanielGalasko - You're right! Sorry! I completely missed that part. :/